# How do I update the database prior to running a PHPUnit Kernel test?

Tags: 9, testing

I've set up the a PHPUnit test environment and configured `SIMPLETEST_DB`. I have also created the following function to update a value in this database. This public function lives outside the test classes, in a service class that interacts with the database.

```
public function updateDatabase(int $uid) {
  $this->database->update('mytable')
    ->fields([
      'type' => 'mytype',
    ])
    ->condition('uid', $uid)
    ->execute();
 }
```

I need to have this value updated prior to running some Kernel tests.

In the `setUp()` function of my test class, I have this code snippet to create a user, and then update this user's field in a custom table:

```
// Create an entry in {mytable} with uid as key:
$this->account = $this->createUser();
// Get the uid:
$uid = $this->account->id();
// Insert in the type field for the entry with key $uid:
$this->container->get('mymodule')->updateDatabase($uid);
```

(where `createUser()` is a trait to create new users that is shared by all test classes.)

This creates no errors when I run the test. I've verfied that the function `updateDatabase()`is called, and the uid for the first user created is "1".

Creating the user works, but updating the database doesn't work. An assert that relies on the field `type` in `{mytable}` is set to `mytype` for this user fails.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Is there actually an entry in mytable with uid 1? Nothing in your code as posted seems to create the row you'd need for this to work. An update that doesn't match on any rows will not return an error, so it's quite possible this is the cause.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong Yes. The call to createUser() does insert this entry. I've verified that this part of the code works. It is the call to updateDatabase() that appear to do nothing.